# What does this conditional test really do?

Tags: ruby

I really dont understand the real utility of the following conditional test inside the *price=(amount)* method...

```
class Ticket
    attr_accessor :price
    def initialize(price)
        @price=price
        puts "The price is #{price}"
    end
    def price=(amount)
        if (amount*100).to_i==amount*100
            @price=amount
            puts "The new price is #{amount}"
        else
            puts "The price seems to be malformed"
        end
    end
end
x=Ticket.new(21)
x.price=100.22
```

How can it check if the input is malformed? I'm a beginner, sorry. I just cant get the logic behind it.

Comment: When encountering code you don't understand, especially when it's this simple, the best approach is to play computer. Pick a bunch of values to send to `price=`, like ints, floats of various values, strings, nils, etc. Then see what each does.

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried as you attempted to figure it out?

The first step is to open up Ruby's IRB (or Pry) and enter the part in question and poke at it. For instance, this is what I get when I poke at it in Pry:

```
[1] (pry) main: 0> amount = 1
1
[2] (pry) main: 0> (amount*100).to_i==amount*100
true
[3] (pry) main: 0> amount = 1.0
1.0
[4] (pry) main: 0> (amount*100).to_i==amount*100
true
[5] (pry) main: 0> amount = 0.1
0.1
[6] (pry) main: 0> (amount*100).to_i==amount*100
true
[7] (pry) main: 0> amount = 0.001
0.001
[8] (pry) main: 0> (amount*100).to_i==amount*100
false
```

After looking at that output, what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

As Ruby is not strongly typed, it's seems to me an attempt to verify two things:

- the input is an integer or a float
- there is no more than two digits (5.331 is NOK, while 5.33 is OK)

in other words, the check verify that the number trucated to two digits is the same that the original number.

Exemple:

```
(5.331*100)=533.1
(5.331*100).to_i=533
```

last digit has been lost....

In terms of programming, this might not be the best way to do it and an exception is better to report error in that case